# Agregar un botón a Tab de JTabbedPane

Tags: java, botón

No puedo agregar un botón a mi tab. Este botón cumplirá la función de agregar una tab nueva.
 Lo estoy creando en Swing y según tengo entendido hay que poner un botón dentro de un `JPanel` y ese panel agregarlo al `JTabbedPane`.

Código:

```
tabRonda = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
JPanel pane = new JPanel();
pane.add(new JButton(new ImageIcon("plus.png")));
tabRonda.addTab("",pane)
```

también probé con `tabRonda.add("",pane);`

El problema es que el botón se agrega dentro del panel y no al tab

Captura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

Saludos,

> (...) según tengo entendido hay que poner un botón dentro de un JPanel
>   y ese panel agregarlo al JTabbedPane.

No, para eso que indicas, no debes hacer eso, puesto que lo que harás es crear una nueva pestaña (tab) y el `JPanel` será el **contenido** de esa nueva pestaña. Y es precisamente lo que te ocurre, creaste una nueva pestaña, añadiste el `JPanel` y en ese `JPanel` un `JButton`, y ese es tu resultado.

Lo que puedes hacer, y tal vez pueda servirte, es utilizar el método `insertTab(...);`, configurar los parámetros según lo requieras y un evento `MouseListener`.

A forma de prueba he creado este pequeño código:

- Icono utilizado para la pestaña: [image: icono_16x16]

---

```
JTabbedPane tabRonda = new JTabbedPane();

ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("add.png")); // Icono de pestaña
tabRonda.insertTab("", icon, null, "Nueva ronda", 0); // Inserta una pestaña por defecto para agregar las demás pestañas
tabRonda.getModel().clearSelection(); // Deselecciona las pestañas (por estética)

tabRonda.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() { // Se agrega el evento
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        JTabbedPane tabRonda = (JTabbedPane) e.getSource(); // Obtiene el JTabbedPane

        if (tabRonda.getSelectedIndex() == 0) { // Comprueba si la pestaña seleccionada es la primera pestaña (utilizada para agregar más pestañas)
            int tab = tabRonda.getTabCount(); // Obtiene la cantidad de pestañas (esto para agregar el nombre nuevo a la pestaña)

            JPanel pane = new JPanel(); // JPanel de prueba 
            pane.add(new JLabel("ESTA ES LA PESTAÑA RONDA " + tab)); // JPanel de prueba
            // Básicamente aquí debes añadir el contenido de la nueva pestaña que desees

            tabRonda.insertTab("Ronda " + tab, null, pane, "Ronda " + tab, tab); // Inserta una nueva pestaña llamada Ronda <tab>, donde <tab> es el número de pestaña.
            tabRonda.setSelectedIndex(tab); // Selecciona la nueva pestaña creada
        }

    }
});

add(tabRonda); // Agrega todo el componente JTabbedPane (en mi caso en un  JFrame, pero en tu caso donde lo necesites).
```

Sólo deberías ajustar todo ese código a tus necesidades.

---

Código en ejecución:

[image: gif]

Comment: funcionó a la perfeccion!
para entenderlo, lo que yo quería era un boton para añadir una pestaña, en vez de eso le pusiste un listener a las pestañas donde cada vez que se acicone la con el index 0 se añade una pestaña con un panel que yo elija

Gracias!

Comment: Exacto, lo pensé así porque prácticamente, cada vez que presionas sobre una pestaña, ellas actúan como un botón, que era lo que tú buscabas

Comment: Estuve tratando de poner un JTable en el panel autogenerado, pero no me resulta. el codigo es  el mismo solo que creo un `JTable  table = new JTable` y se lo agrago al JPanel asi `pane.add(table)`. Cabe mencionar que el  JTable se llena con una consulta desde una DB

Comment: Agrega primero la `JTable` a un `JScrollPane`, y luego agrega ese `JScrollPane` al `JPanel` que indicas

Comment: La tabla se agregaría así al `JScrollPane`: `scrollPane.setViewportView(table);`, luego lo agregas al `JPanel` así: `pane.add(scrollPane);`